# Keeping my repository generic using createquery

Tags: entity-framework, repository

For my repository using the entity framework i'm using the following method to return a IList.

```
 public virtual IList<TEntity> ToList(Func<TEntity, bool> expression)
 {   
    return  Context.CreateQuery<TEntity>("[" + EntitySetName + "]")
                                       .Where<TEntity>(expression).ToList();
 }
```

The expression parameter allows me to alter the result, but this is not to my expectations. Since `createquery` is first evaluated and afterwards my `where` is applied. I'm using this with tables with over 2 mil. records.

Does anybody have a solution how to keep the method generic, but with the abillity to control the outcome without loading all records first?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to change the type of your argument to one which can be converted to SQL:

```
public virtual IList<TEntity> ToList(Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> expression)
```

Note the Expression.